# Solr Exception : org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream

Tags: java, curl, solr

I got this exception :

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1817)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:639)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I try to index some CSV files using CURL. **First** I've tried this in shell :

```
 curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update/csv -F "stream.file=/home/usersolr/Data/production/MyFile_1373882442023" -F  "commit=true" -F "header=false" -F "fieldnames=`cat /home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header`"
```

and it works because, I got the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1782</int></lst>
</response>
```

**Then**, I wanted to integrate this command line within my Java application, I've written this code :

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = "curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update/csv -F \"stream.file=/home/usersolr/Data/production/MyFile_1373882442023\" -F  \"commit=true\" -F \"header=false\" -F \"fieldnames=`cat /home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header`\"";          
    System.out.println(cmd);
    runtime.exec(cmd);
```

And I got the `SolrException`:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream.
```

And my document isn't indexed. The cmd string that I display in the console is exactly the same that the shell command above.

I don't manage the `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` methods. Is it linked to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For runtime.exec you need to have an array of your command like so:

```
String cmd[] = new String[]{"curl", "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/csv", "-F", "\"stream.file=/home/usersolr/Data/production/MyFile_1373882442023\"", "-F"  "\"commit=true\"", "-F", "\""header=false\"", "-F", "\"fieldnames=`cat /home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header`\""};
```

Comment: okay. So the problem probably comes from there ? I have to put all my arguments in a tab and use the runtime.exec(String cmdarray[]) ?

Comment: Correct, If you just replace what I put with you line it should work

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try.

Comment: I got the same mistake ... I think the error come from the space in "fieldnames=`cat /home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header`" because I got a response like that : fieldnames=`cat+/home/usersolr/Data/header/SGs_header` I got a + character. Do you know how to solve it because I can't escape this symbol with \ ?

Comment: why do you have a + symbol, I am not following on that

Comment: I don't know that's that's the response I got :
INFO: [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/csv params={"header=false"&"fieldnames=`cat+/home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header`"&"stream.file=/home/usersolr/Data/production/MyFile_1373882442023"&"commit=true"} {} 0 1

Comment: It seems that it is solrs way of encoding it. Instead of treating it as a space (%20) it uses a +. I would see if there is a way to decode it, or you can just do a String.replace("+"," ")

Comment: I've tried to replace the "cat /home/usersolr/Data/header/My_header" by the value in my file to delete the space symbol and I got the same error. So I think the problem come from another cause... But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input to the URL is not being submitted thus getting "missing content stream" error.

Try following command, it should work.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?stream.file=exampledocs/books.csv&stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

## NOTE: The full path, or a path relative to the CWD of the running solr server must be used.